# Can DataContext.ExecuteQuery process the whole where statement

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, linq-to-sql, executequery

I'm trying to fix a problem in an ASP.NET application which uses DataContext.ExecuteQuery to execute sql statement. The query has this part:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Accounts.SalesRepId = dbo.Contacts.ContactId WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", whereClauses) + @"
```

where "whereClauses" is a List of strings. This way, a search functionality is implemented into the query. Problem appears when an open search is run for a string like "O'Donnel" which obviously run query into an error. I have been asked to fix this problem. My approach was to substitute the where statement with "{0}" in the query and then pass it as a parameter in ExecuteQuery method. What I achieved is:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Accounts.SalesRepId = dbo.Contacts.ContactId {0}

var where = "WHERE 1=1";
_db.ExecuteQuery<AccountModel>(query, where)
```

but it doesn't work? When I substitute the whole where part with just a parameter for it everything is fine:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Accounts.SalesRepId = dbo.Contacts.ContactId WHERE 1={0}

var where = "1";
_db.ExecuteQuery<AccountModel>(query, where)
```

My question - is it then possible to inject the whole where statement dynamically into DataContext.ExecuteQuery method, or can I pass specific parameters only using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [help page for the `ExecuteQuery` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534292%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can't pass the *whole* where clause as a parameter because a query like `select * from myTable @param` isn't valid SQL, whereas `select * from myTable where myField = @param` *is* valid SQL.

So, in answer to your specific question - no, you can't do this by passing parameters to `ExecuteQuery`.

However, why not build up the query in code before you pass it to `ExecuteQuery`?

e.g.

```
var query = "select * from myTable where 1=1" + string.Join(" AND ", whereClauses);
var result = _db.ExecuteQuery<AccountModel>(query);
```